# YouTrack - send out email to requester when issue is resolved

Tags: youtrack

We have email integration setup such that users can email YouTrack as a Help Desk. What I would like to setup is a workflow such that when the issue moves to a resolved state the requester will get a notification that the issue is fixed.

I can add another field in there for "requested by" as a string and create a workflow that fills that in with the requester email address (who is not a YouTrack user, hence the string) and then use that in another workflow but first I was wondering if:

1. That is the best approach and
2. anyone have an existing workflow they'd like to share to help me get started?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are several options to choose a reporter for an issue created from email (i.e. - create new users for every email or post all the emails from the one selected user, like `Mailbox`), which one do you use?

Comment: @Leaom I am going to setup one user called HelpDesk and post all the emails from that one user. I will also setup a postprocessing rule looks as follows: HelpDesk From ${from} this way that string field "HelpDesk From" is automatically filled with the requester's email address. Now I would like a workflow to send an email to the address on that field when the issue is created and resolved